# Posting children to a Structure

Tags: structure, controller, saveentry

This question is a follow up of a previous question see: ([Entry Form - Multiple Entries & Entry Type & Parent](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22749/entry-form-multiple-entries-entry-type-parent))

I am trying to add multiple children to a pre-existing multi level structure:

```
Level 1
--Level 2 (The parent where I am adding the children)
----Child 1
----Child 2
..etc
```

My Controller:

```
public function actionSaveAnimals(){
$this->requirePostRequest();

if($rodentsData = craft()->request->getParam('rodent')){
  $rodentErrors = [];
  foreach ($rodentsData as $rodentData){
      if (array_key_exists('entryId', $rodentData) && $rodentId = $rodentData['entryId']) {
          if (!$rodent = craft()->elements->getElementById($rodentId)) {
              throw new Exception('Could not find rodent with the given Id');
          }
      } else {
          $rodent = new EntryModel();
          $rodent->typeId = 6; // change your entryType Id here
          $rodent->sectionId = craft()->request->getParam('sectionId');
          $rodent->parentId = craft()->request->getParam('parentId');
          $rodent->authorId = craft()->request->getParam('authorId');
      }

      $rodent->getContent()->setAttributes($rodentData['fields']);

      if (!craft()->entries->saveEntry($rodent)) {
          $rodentErrors[] = $rodent->getErrors();
      }else{
          $rodentErrors = [];
      }
  }
  // include errors of each item
  craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
      'rodentErrors' => $rodentErrors
  ));
}
```

}

And my form:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
{# your plugin name and function name #}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="experiment/SaveAnimals">
{# the id of your section for me its 4 you need to change this value to your section Id #}
<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="4">
{# enable the entry #}
<input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
{# id of your entry leave it blank to insert a new entry, insert a id to change an existing entry#}
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="parentId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="authorId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

<div class="fields">
  <div class="field mt3">
    <label class="f5 lh-copy pb2" for="title">Amount of Animals</label>
    {#<input class="pa3 input-reset ba bw0 br2 w-100" type="number" id="Cage__Amount" placeholder="5" max="10" required>#}
    <input type="text" name="rodent[0][fields][title]" value="Add Identifier">
    <input type="text" name="rodent[1][fields][title]" value="Add Identifier">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field submit mv4">
  <button class="bg-dark-blue white ph3 pv2 input-reset pointer ba bw0 f5 dib lh-copy w-100" type="submit">Create experiment</button>
</div>
```

I am currently getting this error:

Trying to get property of non-object

From EntriesService.php(468)

```
if ($entry->getSection()->type != SectionType::Structure)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Is the ID of your entry type 6? Because that was my ID - you did not even remove my hint to change it. If yours is not 6 then you know why this error occurs

Comment: Hi Robin, yes the my entry type is 6, thanks! -Graham

Comment: Hi Graham, this is really creepy because when I copy your code into my craft (I did not delete the structure I created the last time for you) Your script adds 2 children to the cage. https://imgur.com/a/eoHzH would you please do `var_dump($rodent->getSection());die();` right before you save the entry and tell me if your result is something like `object(Craft\SectionModel)` if not then please just include a `$section = craft()->sections->getSectionById(4)` right at the start of your controller, and check if `$section->handle` is your correct handle. My guess is: your ids are wrong

Comment: Hi Robin - my section id was wrong, it has changed recently! Debugging is something I need a better grasp of. Thanks a bunch for the quick replies again!

Comment: You are welcome. Since I have not done very much you could answer your question and mark it. Otherwise this topic will be pumped up from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section ID was incorrect - set correctly and this function works.